# how to include absolute css path using add_editor_style() in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

How to include external css like google font `http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato` using add_editor_style() ?

when i add `add_editor_style('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato');`, in source code will show like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" data-mce-href="http://203.223.152.159/~marineac/wp-content/themes/twentyten/http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&amp;ver=342-201106301" href="http://203.223.152.159/~marineac/wp-content/themes/twentyten/http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&amp;ver=342-201106301">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`mce_css`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/mce_css) filter. Not tested:

```
function so_17961871( $mce_css ) {
    if ( ! empty( $mce_css ) )
        $mce_css .= ',';
    $mce_css .= 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato';

    return $mce_css;
}

add_filter( 'mce_css', 'so_17961871' );
```

Comment: could you please look http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/214858/how-to-hide-product-attribute-from-quick-edit-panel-woocommerce

Answer (score 1):

This was patched in [changeset 24735](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/24735) which I believe is part of 3.6 or 3.6.1.

Comment: Yes indeed. Note that if you want to use multiple font faces (e.g., `$font_url = 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700'`), you need to url encode the commas: Do `str_replace( ',', '%2C', $font_url )` before passing to `add_editor_style`.

Comment: Hi could you please look at this question http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/214858/how-to-hide-product-attribute-from-quick-edit-panel-woocommerce